# Putting table attributes in center of the cell problem

Tags: tables

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forloop}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[numerals=Devanagari]{bengali}
\setmainlanguage{bengali}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\bengalifont[Script=Bengali]{Akaash}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=0cm,top=0cm,bottom=0cm]{geometry}
\newcommand{\aline}{\\\hline \arabic{theyflines} &&&&&&&\rule{0cm}{0.5cm}}
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\newcounter{theyflines}
%\begin{center}
%Extension - 1
%\end{center}
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{|p{0.15cm}|p{6cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1.3cm}|p{1cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{4.5cm}|p{3cm}|}
\hline
{\tiny ক্রমিক} নং & নাম & রুম নং & ডিপার্টমেন্ট & বর্ষ & সেশন & মোবাইল নং & জেলা
\forloop{theyflines}{1}{\value{theyflines} < 40}{\aline}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

I want to use centering for `নাম`,`ডিপার্টমেন্ট`, `মোবাইল নং`...
I also use `\begin{tabular}{|p{0.15cm}|pc{6cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1.3cm}|p{1cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{4.5cm}|p{3cm}|}`  |**pc**{6cm}|p{1.5cm} but results disgusting.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: any news? if no one answer below not fulfill your expectation, than please clarify your question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this helps: you have to use `array` package with the `m` definition (as pointed out by `@TeXnician`) as shown below

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[left=0in, top=0in,bottom=0in]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
    \noindent\begin{table}\centering\begin{tabular}{|m{0.15cm}|m{6cm}|m{1.5cm}|m{1.3cm}|m{1cm}|m{1.5cm}|m{4.5cm}|m{3cm}|}
        \hline
        {\tiny a} jhf& nasg & vafds & easdf & aasdf & hadf& easdf & qadsf\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}\end{table}
\end{document}
```

to achieve

[image]

As per OP's new updated question. Please use `multirow` package to achieve what you desire. Example:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[left=0in, top=0in,bottom=0in]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
    \noindent\begin{table}\centering\begin{tabular}{|p{0.15cm}|p{6cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1.3cm}|p{1cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{4.5cm}|p{3cm}|}
        \hline
        {\tiny a}& \multirow{2}{*}{nasg} & \multirow{2}{*}{vafds} & \multirow{2}{*}{vafds}  & \multirow{2}{*}{vafds}  & \multirow{2}{*}{vafds} & \multirow{2}{*}{vafds}  & \multirow{2}{*}{vafds} \\
        jhf&&&&&&&\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In order to center the text in the cell, you can use `multicol` environment as shown below:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[left=0in, top=0in,bottom=0in]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
    \noindent\begin{table}\centering\begin{tabular}{|p{0.15cm}|p{6cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1.3cm}|p{1cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{4.5cm}|p{3cm}|}
        \hline
        {\tiny a}& \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{nasg}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{vafds}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{vafds}}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{vafds}}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{vafds}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{vafds}}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{vafds}} \\
        jhf&&&&&&&\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}\end{table}
\end{document}
```

This will render

[image]

> Disclaimer: I dont have `Bengali` fonts in my PC :/

Comment: What for do you need the new column type? `m` is already defined and simply putting everything into `m` columns instead of `p` is already sufficient.

Comment: @TeXnician Thanks for the remark --> update my snippet.

Comment: Your answer does not fit with the requirement. Please, see the question again. I edited the question for clarifying.

Comment: @alhelal Please find the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

with use of the macro `makecell` from the package of the same name and defining new column type which center the cells contents  you can obtain desired format of the first table's row:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0in]{geometry}
\usepackage{makecell}
\newcolumntype{Q}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\begin{document}
    \noindent\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|Q{6cm}|Q{1.5cm}|Q{1.3cm}|Q{1cm}|Q{1.5cm}|Q{4.5cm}|Q{3cm}|}
         \hline
        \makecell{a\\ jhf}
        & nasg & vafds & vafds & vafds & vafds & vafds & vafds  \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}\end{table}
\end{document}
```

or if you like to have content in the first smaller size, i.e.: `\tiny` or `\scriptsize` or ... size than change the code of the first cell to

```
\makecell{{\scriptsize a}\\ jhf}
```

note:

- since i haven't `bengaly` fonts i  borrowed text in table from [Raaja's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/70891/raaja) answer.
- your table is to wide to be fit on the page (in calculation of column widths you should consider `\tabcolsep` (16 of them) and `\arrayrulewidth` (9 of them) ...