# ! misplaced \noalign problem on using \centering in table last cell

Tags: alignment

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/polyglossia/gloss-bengali.ldf
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/polyglossia/devanagaridigits.sty)
 (/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/polyglossia/bengalidigits.sty))

Package polyglossia Warning: gloss-bengali.ldf is already loaded! on input line
 5.

(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/polyglossia/gloss-english.ldf)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifvtex.sty))
(./notYet3daysList.aux)
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: xetex

Overfull \hbox (6.22787pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 19--19
[]\TU/Akaash(0)/m/n/5 ক্রমিক

Overfull \hbox (3.89633pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 19--19
\TU/Akaash(0)/m/n/10 নং| 
! Misplaced \noalign.
\hline ->\noalign 
                  {\ifnum 0=`}\fi \hrule \@height \arrayrulewidth \futurelet...
l.20 ...lines}{1}{\value{theyflines} < 25}{\aline}
                                                  \\
?
```

Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forloop}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[numerals=Devanagari]{bengali}
\setmainlanguage{bengali}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\bengalifont[Script=Bengali]{Akaash}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=0.1cm,right=0.1cm,top=0.1cm,bottom=0.1cm]{geometry}
\newcommand{\aline}{\\\hline \arabic{theyflines} &&&&&&&\rule{0cm}{1cm}}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
যাদেরকে আমরা এখন পর্যন্ত ৩ দিনের জন্য বের করতে পারি নাই, তাদের নামের তালিকা 
\end{center}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\newcounter{theyflines}
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{|p{0.15cm}|p{5.2cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1.3cm}|p{1cm}|p{1.4cm}|p{4cm}|p{2.9cm}|}
\hline
{\tiny \centering ক্রমিক} নং & \centering নাম & \centering রুম নং & \centering ডিপার্টমেন্ট & \centering বর্ষ & \centering সেশন & \centering মোবাইল নং & \centering জেলা 
\forloop{theyflines}{1}{\value{theyflines} < 25}{\aline}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Without using `\centering` in `\centering জেলা` it works, but when I put `\centering` before `জেলা` it results the error.

[image]

Comment: Please check the `updated` answer for your question here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/445085/putting-table-attributes-in-center-of-the-cell-problem/445087#445087

Comment: @RaajaG I can't use your answer because that seems to me more broad and hard than mine. Thank you for your job.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

note if you do `{\tiny \centering ক্রমিক}&` it will not center as you close the group before the paragraph ends, If you want the whole cell centred you can remove the `{}` but in cases where it is just some of the text, add a blank line or `\par` before the `}`

and add `\arraybackslash` to avoid the problem if the cell ends in `\\` so

```
{\tiny \centering\arraybackslash ক্রমিক \par} নং &
```

The `\arraybackslash` is not needed if the cell ends with `&` (or if it is inside a `{}` group) only if it ends with `\\` but it doesn't do any harm to use it in all table cells after `\centering`.

Comment: I have to close the `\tiny` with `{}` because I want to use small font for part of the text of 1st cell. I don't understand your answer clearly. Would you please use my MWE to provide an answer?

Comment: @alhelal sorry I misread your example, just use `\centering\arraybackslash` and ignore the other comments I'll fix the answer later, not tine now

Comment: @alhelal sorry I misread your example, You can just use `\centering\arraybackslash`. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Load

```
\usepackage{ragged2e}
```

and replace `\centering` by `\Centering` (Uppercase C). However, something like

```
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\Centering}p{#1}}
```

and then using `P{0.15cm}` makes sense; no need for `\Centering`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Would you please tell me what is the problem in using `\centering` where it works for rest of the cell except the last one?

Comment: `\centering` redefines ``\\`` which is a problem in the last column. `\Centering` saves the old definition and restores it.

Comment: @alhelal `\centering` redefines `\\ ` locally so that it makes a centred line break, but in a table cell that is bad as it means `\\ ` does not end the table row, `\arraybackslash` just redefines `\\ ` back to its normal array/tabular meaning.

Comment: @Herbert the problem with `\Centering` (which is generally better than `\centering`) is that it isn't really usable for one-line paragraphs which are common in tables and seem to be the case here.